# Has there ever been an example in the Star Wars Expanded Universe where a new tech was introduced that is obsolete to the real world?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

I’m trying to think of something in the EU that the galaxy thinks is high-tech/advanced/new that is completely obsolete now in 2023. This is built on my belief that much of Star Wars “primitive” tech is actually more advanced than we think BUT I'm sure there are some examples of the inverse. Do you remember any?

Comment: Does the ewoks using tree traps counts ?

Comment: Does time period make a difference? That is, would it count if there was a story set 30,000 years before the films where computers are brand new?

Comment: Any time period counts but 30,000 isn’t an example because there aren’t any stories that far. The Dawn of the Jedi was only 25k

Comment: It's set in a galaxy far, far away. Not far, far in the future. Primitive and advanced is kind of relative. Just because our path of invention and discovery happened a certain way, doesn't mean theirs followed the same path at all. What might be advanced for us is primitive for them, and vice versa.

Comment: @Mufasa Strictly speaking it's also *long, long ago*.

Comment: In a recent episode of The Mandalorian, an (albeit robotic) office boy delivers what seem to be microfiches to desks on which the participants of the amnesty program do manual data entry (real world has wifi and computers that do batch processing). It is hard to say if that is considered modern, though, it might be part of the "therapy" (as is electroconvulsive therapy, which has fallen somewhat out of favour in the real world).

Comment: Okay. That works thank you!